# Installing RMarkdown packages in RStudio does not work on Windows 7

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I have installed RStudio 0.98 on Windows 7 64bit and when I try to create a new RMarkdown script for the first time, it asks me to install RMarkdown (packages or something).

When I confirm this, the process fails, throwing the following error(s):

```
Installing package into 'C:/Users/grosseti/AppData/Roaming/R'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Warning messages:
1: running command '"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\grosseti\AppData\Roaming\R" "C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/packages/rmarkdown_0.3.10_b96214b9ac86b437067a0aa21442203f52face83.tar.gz"' had status 1 
2: In utils::install.packages("C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/packages/rmarkdown_0.3.10_b96214b9ac86b437067a0aa21442203f52face83.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package 'C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/packages/rmarkdown_0.3.10_b96214b9ac86b437067a0aa21442203f52face83.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status
```

The German sentence

```
Der Befehl "C:\Program" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
```

basically means that the "command C:\Program is either wrongly spelled or cannot be found".

I am pretty sure that it has something to do with escaping, as there is a whitespace in C:\Program Files.

But what do I know, shouldn't this just work? Also notice that there are sometimes `/` in use, sometimes `\`.

Output of `.libPaths()`:

```
[1] "C:/Users/grosseti/AppData/Roaming/R" "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library"
```

(Hint: I set the "C:/Users/grosseti/AppData.." path manually in `RProfile.site`.)

Where do I start???

Comment: For help you and others troubleshooting it's helpful to run Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE = 'en') when you open a project. This way the errors and warnings will be in english and therefore easier to find on the internet and easier for us to understand them.