# Installing R under Program Files

Tags: r, windows

I installed R version 3.2.0 in my "C:\Program Files" folder, and then installed RStudio. When I tried to run an R markdown file, it prompted me to install the Rmarkdown package *from source*. However, I found that [Installing RMarkdown packages in RStudio does not work on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969462/installing-rmarkdown-packages-in-rstudio-does-not-work-on-windows-7).

Digging a little deeper I found that the `R CMD --help` command worked, but every `R CMD <command>` and `R CMD <command> --help` fails with

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

If I had tested my installation, I would have found the problem with

```
Sys.setenv(LC_COLLATE = "C", LANGUAGE = "en")
library("tools")
testInstalledBasic("both")
```

since that fails by calling R CMD BATCH during its execution.

The only solution I could find was to uninstall R and reinstall it a "C:" instead of "C:\Program Files."

It seems like installing R into the "Program Files" folder should be possible. Is there some configuration that would make that possible? Or is there some reason this basic scenario isn't supported?

Comment: Have you tried installing the rmarkdown package by hand? CRAN appears to have binaries for Windows...

Comment: Though there may be a way, since I was dealing with a lot of other similar problems at the time, I chose to install *R* and RStudio in directories like `c:\R\R-3.2.0\ ` and `c:\R\RStudio\ `. The latter has absolutely no problem (that I've experienced), but keeping all of the programs (and Rtools) and such within the `c:\R\ ` directory made some of my work simpler. Completely a technique, and reliant on you having sufficient permissions on your computer.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik The latest binary for RMarkdown is installed by default, but RStudio requires the newest version available with `type=source` which is newer than the binary. I tried installing as manually as it gets. using R CMD INSTALL. That's how I found  a much bigger problem, the one I am asking about: `R CMD INSTALL` and `R CMD INSTALL --help` don't work after a clean install using the default parameters on my system. Also, the installation test  `testInstalledBasic("both")` is not successful.

Comment: How are you installing R, and in particular does it help to use the PATH `C:/Progra~1/...` (dir /x c: for hints) rather than the long path name?

Comment: It's a long shot, but do you have the tool chain installed?

Comment: My vanilla, OEM version of windows has 8dot3 name creation disabled, so I cannot use the short path @MartinMorgan. I could try enabling that to see if it helps though. Enabling and using short path names wouldn't be ideal, but it might work, and I can at least try it as a diagnostic. I have a working configuration at the office that does have short names enabled--that might be the difference.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I had that thought too. I have tried with and without the tool chain installed and the installation test fails the same both ways.

Comment: @r2evans That is exactly where I installed it, and installing it there did work. I want to know if I *have* to install it there or if there is a setting I don't know about. If I do have to install it there, I'd like to know why.

Comment: I don't have a reference handy, but a few years ago I had similar problems, read a post that suggested doing it this way, and I've never looked back. Sorry, no help for the "why" or even if it is the same problem.